# Angularjs datepicker to choose month and year only

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, datepicker

I have this codepen which uses Angularjs Materials datepicker.

http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/zvjZjK

```
.datepickerdemoBasicUsage {
  /** Demo styles for mdCalendar. */ }
  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage md-content {
    padding-bottom: 200px; }
```

However, I want to choose a date that consists of only year and month. I do not need the day information. The date format would be `2008-10-01`, `2008-12-01`.

How can the codepen be modified to support such a date format, if possible?

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/` not sure about mddatepicker but jquery ui has it

Comment: Can one use jquery and angularjs at the same time? Any conflict?

Comment: no conflict use Jquery instead of $ while writing the code to be more safer side

Comment: Can you check it once: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bmonth%5D